# Not sure how to map many to many relationship - Reuse mapping table different entities

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, mapping, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

I'm confused with mapping the following relationship.

I have the following three relevant entities: `User`, `Group`, `GroupUser`.

`User` has information about a user account, a `group` information about the group, and `GroupUser` contains information about the user's membership in the group.

```
public class User
{
    List<GroupUser> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    List<GroupUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class GroupUser
{
    Group Group { get; set; }
    User User { get; set; }
    string Position { get; set; }
    DateTime Joined { get; set; }
}
```

I created a one sided mapping with the following in the `User` group:

```
        HasMany(x => x.Groups)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("UserGroups");
            m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            m.MapRightKey("GroupId");
        });
```

However, when I try and map it again in `Group`

```
        HasMany(x => x.Users)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("UserGroups");
            m.MapLeftKey("GroupId");
            m.MapRightKey("UserId");
        });
```

I get the following error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(274,6) : error 0019: The EntitySet 'UserUserGroup' with schema 'dbo' and table 'UserGroups' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.
```

I want to reuse the mapping table between both entities, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping you use is meant for a situation where the junction table (`UserGroups`) is not part of the conceptual (class) model. In such a situation `User` should have a `List<Group>` and `Group` should have a `List<User>`. (side note: using `ICollection<>` is recommended).

But you've got `class GroupUser` in your model, so it is already mapped (apparently you mapped it to `UserGroups` somewhere else).

In your case it's justified to pull the junction table into the conceptual model, because it contains more than just the two FKs to the tables it connects. The trade-off is that you can't model a many-to-many association.

If you want to get the `Group`s of a `User` you'll have to use a query like

```
var groups = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == 1)
                    .SelectMany(u => u.Groups)
                    .Select(ug => ug.Group)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Gert with using ICollection. I ultimately am going down a similar route to what you proposed, I've removed the mappings I have and I am exposing them as methods which do something similar to what you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, a great description can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093563/map-two-different-entities-to-the-same-table)

Currently I have used Entity Splitting if my model is one to one but other wise you cant map two models to the same table.