# 2 related entities into 1 table using Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have two classes. Foo and FooSettings.

```
Foo
- Id
- Name
- Settings

FooSettings
- ShowName
- Discount
```

And I would like to have a single table in the DB that looks as follows:

```
Foo
- Id
- Name
- Settings
- SettingDiscount
- SettingShowName
```

The example is quite simple and probably should collapse Foo and FooSettings into a single object as well. Our real scenario has quite a few more fields. I think what I have done is organized my entities into bounded contexts (correct me if I am wrong)

I would like to keep those two objects (unless I am completely wrong and there is a better way to do this) but I would like them to map onto a single table in the DB because it is a 1 to 1 relationship.

Is it possible to do this using Entity Framework v5.0 code first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093563/map-two-different-entities-to-the-same-table

Comment: @lliya I found that question but it was asked when entity framework 4.0 was around. I am asking for Entity Framework 5 and hoping it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try Table Splitting as described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting).