# Set own Id key value in seed method in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following code.

```
private void SeedModule(CentralConfigModel context)
        {
            context.ModuleTypes.AddOrUpdate(
                m => m.Name,
                new DomainModel.ModuleType() { Id = 100, Name = "Device" },
        }
```

How can I set to force automatic migrations to set Id in newly added record for value 100?

Comment: Doesn't Id is the primary column? If it is, EF should be auto-incrementing the key. What will happen, if you have removed explicit setting of Id value here?

Comment: I want to remain Id field as PK. When I remove explicit setting, then seed method inserts autoinceremtng values from 1.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to field Id treat as PK. This field shouldn't be incrementted when I insert record via Seed method. I want to put own Id value for each record in seed method.

Comment: You need to set identity insert ON. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265300/identity-insert-during-seeding-with-entityframework-6-code-first).