# Entity Framework pull in table as different model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an edmx diagram with 1 table mapped called `NewsArticles` This table has many properties, and results in an expensive query when getting the entire set.

I sometimes need to bring this entire list back, but not always.

I do however, always need to get the Id and Description properties of all the records in this table, as soon as my application runs.

I have tried to create a cut down version of this table called NewsItem.

Ive added a new dbset to the context.cs file that the edmx wizard created:

```
public virtual DbSet<NewsArticle> NewsArticles { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<NewsItem> NewsArticleLinks { get; set; }
```

`NewsItem` contains an Id(Guid) and a Description(string).

Ive also overidden the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 { 
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new NewsItemConfiguration());
 }
```

And added in a configuration:

```
public class NewsItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<NewsItem>
{
    public NewsItemConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("dbo.NewsArticles");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("Desc");
    }
}
```

Now in my repository, i have a new method which is supposed to go to this table, bring me back every record, but only the two properties for each row and store it in this storage class.

```
public List<NewsItem> GetNewsArticleLinks()
{
   using (var ctx = new NewsArticlesContext())
   { 
     return ctx.NewsArticleLinks.ToList();
   }
}
```

I'm getting this error when i run the .ToList() in the repo:

> The entity type NewsItem is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

**Q:** How can i pull in this table, but as this cut down model collection?

**edit**

I can achieve what I want using projection, but is this the right way.

```
 public List<NewsItem> GetLinks()
 {
       using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
       {
           var query = ctx.NewsArticles.Select(x => new NewsItem { Id = x.Id, Description = x.Desc }).ToList();

           System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(query.ToString());

           return query.ToList();                
       }
  }
```

Comment: Just wondering could you create `view` based on the original `table` with just subset of properties and then map `NewsItem` to that view?

Comment: No because when i first load the page i only bring back the last 5 full NewsArticles, but i need to list all the descriptions to push to my typeahead search box, so they can submit the guid of a legitimate item. It will be the same 1 view.

Comment: Seems as the similar problem described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093563/map-two-different-entities-to-the-same-table?

Comment: I have got it working using projection, will edit to show, but wondered if there was a way of configuring EF, didnt find that question in my searches, thanks.