# Mapping multiple Entities to a single table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have the following (example) Entities:

```
public abstract class Vehicle<TVehicleDetails> where TVehicleDetails : VehicleDetails
{
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public TVehicleDetails? Details { get; set; }
}
public class Car : Vehicle<CarDetails> { }
public class Truck : Vehicle<TruckDetails> { }
```

I'm able to map the Entities `Car` and `Truck` with no issues:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().OwnsOne(p => p.Details).WithOwner();
modelBuilder.Entity<Truck>().OwnsOne(p => p.Details).WithOwner();
```

I also have the following (example) Entity:

```
public class PromotionVehicle<TVehicle, TVehicleDetails>
    where TVehicle : Vehicle<TVehicleDetails>
    where TVehicleDetails : VehicleDetails
{
    public int PromotionVehicleId { get; set; }
    public TVehicle { get; set; }
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; } // this is just an enum
}
```

This is how I'm trying to map `PromotionVehicle<Car, CarDetails>` and `PromotionVehicle<Truck, TruckDetail>` to the same table but to no avail:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PromotionVehicle<Car, CarDetails>>().ToTable("PromotionVehicles");
modelBuilder.Entity<PromotionVehicle<Truck, TruckDetails>>().ToTable("PromotionVehicles");
modelBuilder.Entity<PromotionVehicle<Vehicle<VehicleDetails>, VehicleDetails>>>().ToTable("PromotionVehicles").HasDiscriminator(p => p.VehicleType).HasValue<PromotionVehicle<Car, CarDetails>>(VehicleType.Car).HasValue<PromotionVehicle<Truck, TruckDetails>>(VehicleType.Truck);
```

But, when attempting to create `Migrations`, understandably, EntityFramework throws an `Exception` with an error message mentioning `PromotionVehicle<Car, CarDetails>` is not a descendent of `PromotionVehicle<Vehicle<VehicleDetails>, VehicleDetails>>`.

Effectively what I'm trying to do is tell EntityFramework that when it *looks* at the "PromotionVehicles" table, the column `VehicleType` should tell it which "vehicle table" to *look* at and then load the appropriate `Vehicle<>` Entity (using the `IQueryable<>.Include`).
I believe the necessary bits of information are there to tell EntityFramework where to *look*, the `VehicleType` determines whether to look at "Cars" or "Trucks" and the `VehicleId` satisfies the `ForeignKey` requirement.

Is this configuration at all possible?

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093563/map-two-different-entities-to-the-same-table

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Thanks! I've looked into "Table Splitting" but it doesn't seem to work for my scenario. The "Query View" and "Defining Query" is something I've yet to look into. Update: Those unfortunately do not work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your `PromotionVehicle` is a table that links other tables (a relationship table)

If that is correct you could just store the Ids of the related tables, use EF to store and retrieve those Ids, and then use those Ids to loading each entity in a custom "LoadPromotionVehicle" method

Here is some seudo code

```cs
public class PromotionVehicleRelations
{
    public int PromotionVehicleId { get; set; }
    public Int VehicleId { get; set; } //store just IDs not entity
    public int VehicleDetailsID { get; set; } //store just IDs not entity
    public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; } // enums
}

PromotionVehicle pv ;
PromotionVehicleRelations pvr ;
PromotionVehicleId pvID = 1234 ;

//load the table with the IDs using regular EF mapping
pvr = EF.load(pvID) ;

//populate a new entity with full details that you need using the IDs
pv = LoadPromotionVehicle(pvr) ;

LoadPromotionVehicle(PromotionVehicleRelations pvr) {
  pv.TVehicle = EF.loadVehicle(pvr.VehicleId)
  pv.VehicleDetails = EF.loadVehicleDetails(pvr.VehicleDetailsID) ;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the `PromotionVehicle` Entity does contain some of its own Properties (which I had removed in my question just for brevity). I use `Include` to load the "navigation Entities" just for performance benefits. So, without having to issue multiple calls to the database, EF can simply obtain the necessary data with multiple split queries through a single call. That is also why I wish to use a single table for `PromotionVehicle` as otherwise I could create `PromotionCar` and `PromotionTruck` Entities and just have those mapped to their own tables (but that would result in multiple calls).

Comment: using `Include` with my proposed approach should work. making multiple queries and storying multiple entities should not be perfomance issue, EF alreay optimizes that if you call `SaveChanges` only once.  If this approach does not meet your needs use one of the mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5094536/1461862 -

Comment: Also once you wrap the needed loading logic into a single method, that will also be a "single call" ;-)